# Ajax/PHP - autocomplete value not recognised

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) to run an ajax data query from an mysql db, that returns a table.

This is working fine when text is manually typed into this input form eg:
[image]

But the search form has an autocomplete jquery script that will help the user along. When a value is chosen from the dropdown autocomplete values, the onchange event isn't recognized, no table shows.

My question is, how would I put a button at the end of the search form, to change this to 'onclick' event, rather than 'onchange'? The hurdle I am facing is that the input for 'client_address' is part of a larger form, and clicking submit on any button causes the page to try submit the entire form.

create_wt.php:

```
// autocomplete 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'backend_search_addressWT.php'
        });
    });
</script>
// retrieve data in table
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_get_client_info.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>


<div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($client_address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label>Address</label>
    <div class = "input-group">
        <input id="clientsearch" type="text" name="client_address" onchange="showUser(this.value)" class="input-group form-control" value="<?php echo $client_address; ?>" placeholder="Search by address..."  style="width: 500px;">
        <!---<span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" value="submit" id="ajaxbtn" type="submit">Get Client Info</button>
        </span> -->
    </div>
    <br><div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $client_address_err;?></span>
</div>
```

ajax_get_client_info.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $q = trim($_GET['q']);
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_address LIKE '%".$q."%'");


    //$data = array();

    //while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        // $data[] = ($row);
    //}

    //echo json_encode($data);

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>client_id</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['client_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

EDIT:

create_wt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
            select: function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_get_client_info.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
}
 }
 {
  source: 'backend_search_addressWT.php'
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would not use an additional button, but simply call your showUser function from the autocomplete callback that fires when the user selects a value ... http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: @CBroe I added an EDIT with new version of create_wt.php with your suggestion of calling Showuser from autocomplete function- but neither are working now - does one need to adjust the ID tags?

Comment: I meant _call_ the function in the callback, not move the whole function inside it. (You still need to call that function when the user actually types into the input field, so you need it available “outside” of the handler function.) Besides, you can not just name the parameter `str` and hope it somehow magically gets the right value passed from somewhere. The callback is passed two parameters as described in the docs, `event` and `ui`. In `ui` you find the option the user has chosen from the autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

the *select* event of the autocomplete input does not accept the user's input as an argument but has 2 other: **event**, **ui**.

So you are trying to access the value: **ui.item.value** that is the selected item's value.

So that must be your problem.

**CBroe** has the same answer in the comments.

```
....
function getHint(value) {
  if ((value !== "") && (typeof value !== 'undefined')) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_get_client_info.php?q=" + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return true; // return true to accept the selection of the user
  } else {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    $(this).autocomplete( "close" ); // Close the autocomplete popup manual because by returning false negates the selection but it does not close the popup.
    return false; // return false to negate the selection of the user
  }
}
$( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
    select: function showUser(event, ui) {
      return getHint(ui.item.value);
    },
    change: function showUser(event, ui) {
      return getHint(ui.item.value);
    },
    {
    source: 'http://www.example.com'
    }
 });
 ....
```

Be sure to read the documentation so you know how to treat this case from the start.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please do you mind providing an example script with how this should look? pretty much a beginner and I'm not sure how I would do above.

Comment: thanks! this is not working unfortunately. when the dropdown is selected, the value is not inserted into input, neither does the table show up. CBroe advised not moving whole function inside the callback?

Comment: Yes make a global named function and move the code in there. Make the same thing for the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Change **onchange** in input box to **onkeyup**, that should solve, onchange is mainly used for radio buttons and checkboxes.

```
<input id="clientsearch" type="text" name="client_address" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)" class="input-group form-control" value="<?php echo $client_address; ?>" placeholder="Search by address..."  style="width: 500px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a input type button:

```
<input type="button" name="" id="">
```

and use its `click` event. Input type will not submit the form.